# How do I print out a method within a loop

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I apologize but I am new to programming and I'm having difficulty coding a program.  The original program is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class buildABoat{

    String boatName;      // Boat name
    void buildABoat(){      
        String BoatName;            
    }

    void nameTheBoat() {        
        try {           
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("\n\nWhat should we name this vessel? \n\n");
            this.boatName = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("\n\nThe " + boatName + " is ready to sail!\n");             
        }           
        catch (IOException e) {                 
        }   
    }
}

class proj1{

    public static void main(String[] arg){

        buildABoat boat1;
        buildABoat boat2;
        buildABoat boat3;
        buildABoat boat4;
        buildABoat boat5;

        boat1 = new buildABoat();
        boat2 = new buildABoat();
        boat3 = new buildABoat();
        boat4 = new buildABoat();
        boat5 = new buildABoat();

        boat1.nameTheBoat();
        boat2.nameTheBoat();
        boat3.nameTheBoat();
        boat4.nameTheBoat();
        boat5.nameTheBoat();

        System.out.println("(Press ENTER to exit)");

        try {           
            System.in.read();
        }           
        catch (IOException e) {         
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following:

```
What should we name this vessel?
Enterprise
The Enterprise is ready to sail!
What should we name this vessel?
Columbia
The Columbia is ready to sail!
What should we name this vessel?
Challenger
The Challenger is ready to sail!
What should we name this vessel?
Atlantis
The Atlantis is ready to sail!
What should we name this vessel?
Endeavor
The Endeavor is ready to sail!
(Press ENTER to exit)
```

I tried to change this to the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class buildABoat{    
    String boatName;      // Boat name

    void buildABoat(){
        String BoatName;
    }

    void nameTheBoat() {
        try {           
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("\n\nWhat should we name this vessel? \n\n");
            this.boatName = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("\n\nThe " + boatName + " is ready to sail!\n");             
        }           
        catch (IOException e) {                 
        }   
    }
}

class proj1{

    public static void main(String[] arg){

        Boat[] boat;            
        boat = new Boat[5];    
        for(int i = 0; i <= Boat.Length; i++){          
            nameTheBoat();          
        }           
        System.out.println("(Press ENTER to exit)");

        try {           
            System.in.read();
        }           
        catch (IOException e) {         
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This of course produces the following error:

```
proj1.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
                for(int i = 0; i <= Boat.Length; i++){
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable Length
  location: class Boat
proj1.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
                        nameTheBoat();
                        ^
  symbol:   method nameTheBoat()
  location: class proj1
2 errors
```

What am I missing in the new program?

Comment: Is this [tag:homework]?  If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Comment: This is pretty obviously homework, but my more major issue with it is that it doesn't show much of an effort of debugging.

Comment: I do need to do a better job of debugging.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you have

```
nameTheBoat();
```

in your for() loop you need to have

```
boat[i] = new Boat();
boat[i].nameTheBoat();
```

The reasons are:
1) `nameTheBoat()` is a method that only operates on objects of type `Boat`.  You are not giving it any object to work on.
2) `boat[] = new Boat[5];` initializes an Array object, but doesn't create the 5 new `Boat`s in the `Array` object.  So you need to create each of those 5 `Boat`s before you can run a `Boat` method on them.  Otherwise you'll get a null pointer error.

EDIT: and of course as others mentioned, `boat.length` is the length of the array `boat`, `boat.Length` is wrong.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I was able to get the program to work but I'm now getting an exception.  A little more work and it will be done!  Thank you Joe

Answer (score 2):

use lowercased **length**

```
for(int i = 0; i <= Boat.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `boat.nameTheBoat()` instead of just `nameTheBoat()`

Also

```
for(int i = 0; i <= boat.length; i++){          
        boat[i].nameTheBoat();          
    }
```

boat is the instance of the class `Boat` (probably should be `buildABoat`).  These look like they're compiler errors and not runtime errors, so the compiler should give you some hint (as it does) as to the exact line numbers.

Comment: This is wrong... `nameTheBoat()` belongs to the `buildABoat` class in his code not the `Boat` class which we can't even see.

Comment: Haha, you're right!  Wow -- not only are there several issues with this, but he's evidently referencing a class that we're not seeing.  Good catch, Pete, I just made an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You must try to calculate the length on the object rather than the class. So, it should be boat.length, where boat is your object here

You call a method using the class name, if the method is a static method.

Comment: Somebody who is completely unaware of what I spoke must have downvoted this. Or, the person who downvoted this can very well explain why

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that he wants to iterate over an array of boats, but since his typo (capital Boat in the for loop) makes that unclear, I guess there's a chance that your answer isn't wrong. This is why I hate it when people name instances of objects with the same name as their class and change the capitalization of one letter!

Comment: I kind of gave the answer in a generic way, than going through all his code carefully. After a 12 hour day, its tough though. Felt weird when it was downvoted.

Comment: OK - I did not dive so deep. Just wanted to convey that he had to use the name of the object, rather than the name of the class there. Since, that was something very basic.

Comment: @codezilla I mean absolutely no offense in this, but just as I was confused about the downvote, I'm confused about three upvotes. :)

Comment: Well - you changed your answer so I removed the downvote and turned it into an upvote. Plus some other people probably came along after you changed it. Enjoy!

Comment: @jahroy i don't mind about the votes or points anyways buddy.. ! just trying to gain and  share some knowledge here.. i did not get offended or anything..and still kind of new to the terminology here...

Answer (score 2):

As Nurlan mentions, the first error is because you're using a capital L for the *length* property of an array.  The actual property begins with a lowercase l.

The second error is because the method *nameTheBoat* is part of the class named *buildABoat*, but you're trying to invoke it as if it were part of your main class.  You need an instance of a *buildABoat* object in order to invoke this method.

One other suggestion: to comply with java naming conventions, you should NOT begin the name of a class with a lowercase letter.  Classes should always start with a capital letter.  Methods should always begin with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

The object array you have created is `boat = new Boat[5];`. Ideally you whole code should be like this

```
Boat[] boat = new Boat[5];    
for(int i = 0; i <= Boat.Length; i++){          
boat[i] = new Boat();
boat[i].nameTheBoat();          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

One is that `boat` as an array

```
Boat[] boat;            
boat = new Boat[5];    
for(int i = 0; i <= Boat.Length; i++){          
    nameTheBoat();          
}
```

To access the array `length` it would be `boat.length` instead of what you have.

The next problem I see is your call to `nameTheBoat()`.  That method is part of the `buildABoat` class.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like a constructor with accident.

```
class buildABoat{    
    String boatName;      // Boat name

    void buildABoat(){
        String BoatName;
    }
```

If void buildABoat () would be a method (void says so), why would you declare a local variable in it, and not use it?

And don't repeat the name of a well named attribute as comment.

```
class BuildABoat {    
    private String boatName;   

    public BuildABoat (String name) {
        boatName = name;
    }
```

This would make some sense. You now have a class, which can be instantiated by passing a boatname, which is preserved in the class.

In your Proj1-Class, you split declaration and initialisation. This is a bad habit. Sometimes it's not avoidable, but if it is, avoid it.

```
class Proj1 {

    public static void main(String[] arg){

        BuildABoat [] boat = new BuildABoat[5];    
        for(int i = 0; i <= boat.length; i++) {
            // to make this work, we have to change the 
            // buildABoat
            boat[i] = new BuildABoat (BuildABoat.nameTheBoat ());
        }
        System.out.println ("(Press ENTER to exit)");
        try {           
            System.in.read ();
        }           
        catch (IOException ignored) {         
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The method nameTheBoat has to be static, if we call it without actually having a (builda)boat already.

```
public static String nameTheBoat () {
    try {           
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println ("\n\nWhat should we name this vessel? \n\n");
        String s = br.readLine ();
        System.out.println ("\n\nThe " + s + " is ready to sail!\n");
        return s;
    }
      catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }   
}
```

I hope the code does a little what you intended.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this definitely helped!  Joe